# When using setContentPane it returns JFrame is not applicable for the arguments(GamePanel())

Tags: java, jframe

My Java code is below. I do not know why I keep on running into this error. I am using Java JRE 1.8. Thanks.

```
package Main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Entry Point
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Practice Game");
        //Tells Java to create a window and name it "Practice Game".
        window.setContentPane(new GamePanel());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Tells Java to completely close the program one the red x is pressed
        window.setResizable(false);
        //Tells Java to disable the possibility to Resize the window (False = boolean)
        window.pack();
        //Tells Java to make the screen size the recommended size determined by the computer screen.
        window.setVisible(true);
        //Tells Java to either hide or show the window.
    }

}
```

Comment: What type is GamePanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GamePanel` must extend `JPanel` for you to set it as the content pane.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem. Sorry for the trouble, I am a bit of a noob at programming as of now.